# Avoiding view of vest in T-shirt

Tags: clothing

I have many T-shirts worn during summers.They lack collars.
The problem with it is that the straps of the vest i.e sandoz are visible and it looks very odd.You have to insert it underneath the T-shirt in shoulder parts but it soon comes to its original position and is viewed again.Can anyone help with this problem?
Vest is like [this](https://m.snapdeal.com/product/neva-quilt-white-modal-base/411776270)

Comment: Do you mean an [undershirt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undershirt)?

Comment: Undershirt is US terminology. Vest is UK. [Not to be confused with a US vest, which is a UK waistcoat & goes *over* your shirt]

Comment: Yeah I mean vest in UK terminology

Comment: The description makes this resemble a tank-top type undershirt; these usually have a fairly deep neck cut as well as sleeveless shoulders that ride high, giving what amounts to a strap.  Assuming that's right, it might simplify answering...

Comment: Still not sure what you mean... a picture would make the question clearer.

Comment: Here in the Southern Unites States we call that a "Wife Beater." Other than telling you to wear a thicker shirt, or a darker colored shirt, the only other option I can suggest is to wear only the "vest."

Answer (score 2):

I am fat and face same problem. Vest left strap always visible thru round neck tshirt. I copy the solution from what ladies do to hide bra straps. I sew strap with chit button at left side of tshirt and problem got solved. You can see ladies suits for reference.

Answer (score 1):

A sando vest is a vest, in UK terminology, that is, a garment worn next to the skin, underneath other clothing, either short sleeved or with a straplike cut of varying widths over the shoulders, worn usually for warmth. Choose a different style of vest - there are differences in the cut which make the strap parts over your shoulders rest in different areas over the shoulders, so choosing one with narrower straps, set further apart, is about the only thing you can do. Or stop wearing a vest under your teeshirt - if its warm enough to wear a teeshirt, surely its warm enough to not need a vest beneath. If you're female, a camisole top is better, they have really narrow straps, but again, where the straps sit on the shoulders differs with the cut of the garment.

Comment: I will check if there are any but probability might be less for there are many with same experience so they usually use collared T-shirt.

Comment: You're probably right - men's vests are all pretty similar, and there's no easy answer to this problem. If you know someone handy with a needle (who can sew, in other words), you could cut  off some material and hem the edges, that might solve the problem.